# mysql2: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib after homebrew update

Tags: openssl, macos-mojave, mysql2

After I upgraded mac OS Mojave from `v10.14.0` to `v10.14.2` and all the packages installed with Homebrew I started getting the following error when I run `bin/rails console`:

```
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': dlopen(/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

I tried to uninstall `mysql2` gem and install it with cpp and ld flags:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.4 -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

But it didn't help.

Also I tried to upgrade `mysql2` to the latest version (`v0.5.3` at the time of writing this post), but it didn't work either

`ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` gives me:

```
total 14472
drwxr-xr-x  4 hirurg103  staff      128 Sep 10 16:13 engines-1.1
-r--r--r--  1 hirurg103  staff  2265596 Dec 13 19:06 libcrypto.1.1.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 hirurg103  staff  3930864 Sep 10 16:13 libcrypto.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hirurg103  staff       19 Sep 10 16:13 libcrypto.dylib -> libcrypto.1.1.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 hirurg103  staff   485860 Dec 13 19:06 libssl.1.1.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 hirurg103  staff   720400 Sep 10 16:13 libssl.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hirurg103  staff       16 Sep 10 16:13 libssl.dylib -> libssl.1.1.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  5 hirurg103  staff      160 Dec 13 19:06 pkgconfig
```

I do not see `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` there `mysql2` complains about

Have you met this error before?
Were you able to fix it and how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.0 [reached EOL on 2019-12-31](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/46876)

Reinstalling `mysql2` gem with `--with-cflags` and `--with-ldflags` arguments pointing to `openssl@1.1` fixed the error:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.4 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"

bundle install
```

Comment: better to update new version since old version doest work. 

`gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"`

what I did remove version completely 

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags=\"-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include\" --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"`

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me ultimately was:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Prior to trying these commands, I also had tried `brew reinstall openssl` several times. I also exported LIBRARY_PATH: `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/` AND I reinstalled ruby via rbenv.

So, if the brew update and upgrade doesn't clear the error for you, perhaps try reinstalling openssl. Then if that doesn't work, reinstall ruby.

Comment: I ran `brew upgrade`, then to fix the issue I reinstalled using `gem uninstall mysql2; bundle install`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using `rbenv`:

```
 brew uninstall openssl
 brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0

 gem uninstall mysql2
 gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0)"
```

Comment: Caution! This is only what you want if you are installing Ruby version 2.3 or older. See: https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap

Comment: This worked for me on Ruby 2.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on my Intel Mac Monterey, installing `mysql2` v `0.5.5` with `ruby-3.2.2`

```
brew install openssl@1.1
brew info openssl@1.1
```

Brew info would give a bunch of information. copy the openssl lib path from the above output, similar to below snippet.

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
```

Now install the `mysql2` gem with the lib path from above. example

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.5 -- --with-openssl-lib="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Same issue on mysql2 0.5.5 with Ruby 3.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was very similar to @Hirurg103, except the --with-cflag didn't work for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10 -- --with-ldflags=\"-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple solution of updating brew works for me

```
  brew update && brew upgrade
```

I also installed **MacPorts** following this instruction [here](https://www.macports.org/index.php)